# Is UNIX time universal

Tags: unix, datetime, timezone, timestamp-with-timezone

I did some research on internet but still confused. Is UNIX time universal time like GMT/UTC or does it vary from place to place like a local time?

I know UNIX time is counted from 1st Jan, 1970 00:00:00 GMT. When I use getTime() function in Java (more specifically Date d= new Date(); long currentTime d.getTime()) I am getting the UNIX time in milliseconds. Now If person A and person B use the same function who are sitting in two different time zones, will they get the same result?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> Now If person A and person B use the same function who are sitting in two different time zones, will they get the same result?

Yes, they will - assuming their clocks are both "correct" of course.

The [`java.util.Date`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) class is basically a wrapper around "the time since the Unix epoch, in milliseconds". Given that the Unix epoch was an *instant* in time (not just "midnight on January 1st 1970", the number of elapsed milliseconds is the same wherever you are. (Ignoring relativity and any discussion of leap seconds...)

(Side-note: at the Unix epoch, it wasn't midnight in Greenwich. It was 1am, because the UK was observing BST at the time. That's British *Standard* Time, not British *Summer* Time - the UK was at UTC+1 from Feb 18th 1968 to October 31st 1971. For more similar trivia, see the [Noda Time user guide trivia page](http://nodatime.org/unstable/userguide/trivia.html).)

Answer (score 7):

The [answer by Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29816332/642706) is correct. I'll add a few thoughts.

[Unix time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) means different things to different people. As that Wikipedia article describes, the basic idea is usually a count of seconds since epoch, with *epoch* being the first moment of 1970 in the [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) time zone. As the name suggests, this approach to time tracking was used in Unix-like operating systems.

## Locality

Does it vary by locality? No. By definition, it represents UTC time zone. So a moment in Unix time means the same simultaneous moment in [Auckland](http://time.is/Auckland), [Paris](http://time.is/Paris), and [Montréal](http://time.is/Montreal). The `UT` in `UTC` means "Universal Time".

Is Unix time universal in the sense of used everywhere? No, certainly not.

## Granularity

First, the granularity. As computer clock chips became more precise, conventional computer systems moved to tracking time by [millisecond](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Millisecond), [microsecond](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsecond), and even [nanosecond](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond). Different software assumes different granularity of time tracking. The java.util.Date/.Calendar classes and [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) library both use millisecond resolution, while the newer [java.time package](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) built into Java 8 assumes nanosecond resolution. Some databases such as [Postgres](http://www.postgresql.org) typically assume microsecond resolution.

[image: Diagram of time-tracking granularity ranging from whole seconds to nanoseconds.]

To quote the Question…

> I am getting the UNIX time in milliseconds

Technically a contradiction in terms, as traditional Unix time or POSIX time is tracked by whole seconds rather than milliseconds.

## Epoch

Secondly, the [epoch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoch_(reference_date)). The first moment of 1970 is far from the only epoch used by various computer systems. A [couple dozen epochs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoch_(reference_date)#Notable_epoch_dates_in_computing) have been used, some with very wide usage. For example, Microsoft Excel and Lotus 1-2-3 spreadsheets, [Cocoa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cocoa_(API)), [GPS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_Positioning_System) satellites, [Galileo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galileo_(satellite_navigation)) satellites, DOS & FAT file systems, and ntp ([Network Time Protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_Time_Protocol)) each using a different epoch ranging from the years 1899 to 2001.

## Avoid Count-From-Epoch

Generally best to avoid focusing on handling date-time values by counting milliseconds (or any granularity) from epoch. Such values are difficult to read and comprehend by humans thereby making debugging difficult and mistakes non-obvious. Add on the possible mistakes from assumptions about the granularity and/or epochs discussed above.

Instead use a decent date-time library. In Java that means either:

- [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/)
- [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html)

Do you track text by collecting groups of 7 or 8 bits? No, you use classes and libraries to do the heavy-lifting of handling character sets, character encoding, and such. Do the same for date-time work.