# I want to get current time in Java but without the Internet and without the system time

Tags: java, time

I want to get the exact current time. I do not want the system time because that can be changed by any person and i want to do this without accessing the internet, is there a way?

Comment: I think the options you rejected in your question are the only two options you have. Pick one.

Comment: If you don't trust the local data and you don't want to get to external data, how would you logically *expect* to get the right time?

Comment: @JonSkeet Thanks, that's a good way to sum it up.

Comment: Is there a hardware system clock, That i can access, like CMOS?

Comment: I think you should address your efforts trying to prevent people to "hack around" with time....

Comment: Dear Downvoters, Why the down-votes? This is a legitimate question. And it turns out there are indeed solutions such as special hardware devices. Please leave a constructive criticism along with your vote.

Comment: See Answers on this duplicate Quetion, [How can I ensure in Java that the current local time is correct?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32194245/642706)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## Time Server

Set up a [time server](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_server) on your local network. Have your app contact that local time server to query the current time.

Consider placing that time server computer in [network’s DMZ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DMZ_%28computing%29) so as to updates from time servers on the Internet such as the [pool.ntp.org project](http://tf.nist.gov/tf-cgi/servers.cgi) or [those provided by the United States federal government (NIST)](http://tf.nist.gov/tf-cgi/servers.cgi).

## Radio Clock

Obtain a [radio clock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radio_clock) with a [USB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB) connection for output of current time  synchronized by a time code transmitted by a radio transmitter connected to a time standard such as an atomic clock. Transmitters are broadcasting in many countries all over the world.

The [Meinberg Global](https://www.meinbergglobal.com/) company, at least, offers [several such devices](https://www.meinbergglobal.com/english/products/usb-clocks.htm).

[image: photo of a couple of radio clock via USB devices]

## GPS

Similar to the radio clocks above, a receiver of GPS ([Global Positioning System](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_Positioning_System)) signals might also capture and relay the [time signal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_signal). Or perhaps [GALILEO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galileo_(satellite_navigation)) or [GLONASS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GLONASS) or [similar systems](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Satellite_navigation#Regional_navigation_satellite_systems).

[image]

## Sundial

Position a [sundial](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sundial) outside a window. Attach a [webcam](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Webcam) to the computer in question. Position the webcam in the window. Write an app to interpret the time of day from current image of the sundial.

[image: photo of a sundial on a pedestal in a garden]

Comment: I think the sundial method is flawed if there is a lot of cloud cover or the sun decides to explode suddenly.