# Java System.currentTimeMillis() in Human Readable Format UTC

Tags: java, android

Similar question might be asked many times but I couldn't find question which ask for Human Readable Format in UTC time.

I want to convert currentTimeMillis() to Human Readable Format for example "YYMMDDHHMMSS". I am trying to use SimpleDateFormat but it returns LocalTime not UTC.

```
long currentTimeMillis = System.currentTimeMillis();
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyMMddHHmm");
Date date = new Date(currentTimeMillis);
String currentTime = dateFormat.format(date);
```

this code gives me LocalTime but I want time in UTC only.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16202956/get-current-time-in-a-given-timezone-android

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/308683/how-can-i-get-the-current-date-and-time-in-utc-or-gmt-in-java

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It may help you. If not get back with problem.

```
long currentTimeMillis = System.currentTimeMillis();
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yy/MM/dd HH:mm");
dateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
Date date = new Date(currentTimeMillis);
String currentTime = dateFormat.format(date);
```