# How Do I Convert System.currentTimeMillis To Time Format? (HH:MM:SS)

Tags: java, android

I am trying to convert System.currentTimeMillis to current time format of (hh:mm:ss). So far this is what I've tried and it's not working right.

```
    Long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

    int hours;
    int minutes;
    int seconds;

    String getSecToStr = currentTime.toString();
    String getTimeStr = getSecToStr.substring(8,13);

    seconds = Integer.parseInt(getTimeStr);

    minutes = seconds / 60;
    seconds -= minutes * 60;

    hours = minutes / 60;
    minutes -= hours * 60;

    String myResult = Integer.toString(hours) + ":" + Integer.toString(minutes) + ":" + Integer.toString(seconds);

    System.out.println("Current Time Is: " + myResult);
```

Any ideas? Much appreciated!

Comment: How is it not working? How does it differ from your expectation?

Comment: System.currentTimeMillis pulls a 13 figure number. I believe those numbers include current date and time. The first 8 numbers I believe is the date and the last 5 is the time. When I use String.substring to assign number characters 8 to 13 as my seconds the end result is the following...

27:13:12 or 5:5:4

That's not what I want. I want the actual time.

Comment: It's not like that. Take a look [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert Milliseconds to "X mins, x seconds" in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/625433/90527), [Java System.currentTimeMillis() in Human Readable Format UTC](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41791292/90527)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are some object that you can use to make this more easy, like `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`.

**First prepare the time in mills:**

```
Long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
```

**Choose your desier format with `SimpleDateFormat`:**

```
SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss");
```

**Create your date object:**

```
Date date = new Date(currentTime);
```

**Apply that format into your date object:**

```
String time = simpleDateFormat.format(date);
```

**Log it:**

```
Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: " + time);
```

**Result:**

```
17:05:73
```

Comment: use `hh:mm:ss` or `HH:mm:ss` instead of `HH:MM:SS`. MM is for month and SS is part of millisecond. hh is for 12-hour format and HH is for 24-hour format. 05 is may and you can't have 73 seconds in a minute

Comment: These terrible date-time classes were supplanted years ago by the modern *java.time* classes with the adoption of JSR 310. Suggesting their use in 2019 is poor advice.

Comment: This Answer ignores the crucial issue of time zone.

Answer (score 6):

## tl;dr

No need for `System.currentTimeMillis();`. Use *java.time* classes.

```
LocalTime.now( 
    ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" )
)
.truncatedTo( 
    ChronoUnit.SECONDS
)
.toString()
```

> 12:34:56

## *java.time*

The modern approach uses the *java.time* classes. Never use the terrible `Date` and `Calendar` classes.

To get the current time-of-day requires a time zone. For any given moment, the time-of-day (and the date) vary around the globe by zone.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Australia/Sydney" ) ;
```

Capture the current time of day as seen in the wall-clock time used by the people of that particular region, that time zone. Obtain a [`LocalTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalTime.html) object.

```
LocalTime lt = LocalTime.now( z ) ;
```

If you want UTC rather than a particular zone, pass the `ZoneOffset.UTC` constant.

Apparently you want to track the time-of-day to the [whole second](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/temporal/ChronoUnit.html#SECONDS). So let’s [lop off](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalTime.html#truncatedTo(java.time.temporal.TemporalUnit)) the fractional second.

```
LocalTime lt = LocalTime.now( z ).truncatedTo( ChronoUnit.SECONDS ) ;
```

Generate text in standard ISO 8601 format by calling `toString`.

```
String output = lt.toString() ;
```

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
- Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)
- Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))
- Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
- For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

[image]

Comment: Hi Basil, a great answer but this approach requires API level 26 which a lot of devices still using less than API 26. I suppose you highlight your answer for API 26 or Higher.

Comment: @Ali See links added to new section at bottom of the Answer for *ThreeTenABP*.

Answer (score 4):

The following is equivalent to the date format HH:mm:ss

```
String.format("%1$TH:%1$TM:%1$TS", System.currentTimeMillis())
```