# get Device current time in UNIX in Android

Tags: android, unix, time

I am using the following code to get current time in UNIX

```
System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000L
```

But it is returning the current GMT but I need the device time in UNIX. for Example, if the time zone is GMT + 5 it should return GMT + 5 but currently it's not.

I even tried this

```
 Date utcDate=new Date();
 utcDate.setTime(System.currentTimeMillis());
long currentTime = utcDate.getTime();
```

but no luck.

All other answers on SO is returning current GMT only. 
I can't hard code the Time Zone as it could be anywhere around the world.

**Update:**

I don't need my device's timezone I need UNIX time in my TimeZone. The Mark Duplicate question is only providing the time zone and Time in Date or Calendar Formate

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get current time in a given timezone : android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16202956/get-current-time-in-a-given-timezone-android)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the current date and time of your timezone in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1305350/how-to-get-the-current-date-and-time-of-your-timezone-in-java)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I have solved it this way

```
       Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

       TimeZone timeZone =  cal.getTimeZone();


        Date cals =    Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getDefault()).getTime();

        long milliseconds =   cals.getTime();

        milliseconds = milliseconds + timeZone.getOffset(milliseconds);


       long unixTimeStamp = milliseconds / 1000L;
```

Hope it helped others.

Thanks

Comment: Thank you this helped me with the exact same issue.