# Android / JAVA: Get current time based on timezone

Tags: java, android, android-studio

regarding my question above, I want to get current date time based on time zone (Kuala Lumpur). Can I know how to do?

Below is my current code:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    btnTime = findViewById(R.id.btnTime);
    tvTime = findViewById(R.id.tvTime);

    btnTime.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss",  Locale.getDefault());

            String time = "Current time - " + format.format(calendar.getTime());

            tvTime.setText(time);
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get current time in a given timezone : android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16202956/get-current-time-in-a-given-timezone-android)

Comment: As an aside consider throwing away the long outmoded and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` and friends, and adding [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) to your Android project in order to use `java.time`, the modern Java date and time API. It is so much nicer to work with.

Comment: Does your code give you what you want? What was the question again, please? If there’s any trouble with your code, please specify precisely how observed result differs from current date time in Kuala Lumpur.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Malaysia observes GMT+8, and you can set the `TimeZone` of your `SimpleDateFormat` like

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", Locale.getDefault());
format.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+08:00"));
String time = "Current time - " + format.format(calendar.getTime());
```

Or, better, switch to the [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) backport of `java.time` like

```
ZonedDateTime klDateTime = LocalDateTime.now().atZone(ZoneId.of("Asia/Kuala_Lumpur"));
String time = "Current time - " + klDateTime.format(DateTimeFormatter
        .ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"));
```

Comment: the first one is better. Thanks mate

Comment: Opinions differ. IMHO the first one is clearly inferior. The classes `SimpleDateFormat`, `TimeZone` and `Date` are all poorly designed and all long outdated. Also `Asia/Kuala_Lumpur` is correct while `GMT+08:00` may be correct today and may be incorrect for historic and/or future dates.

Comment: On the other hand the second one is incorrect.  I just got `Current time - 2019-12-29 09:30:49`, but the time in Kuala Lumpur is 16:30. It shouldn’t be hard to fix, though.