# How to set a timezone with org.joda.time?

Tags: java, jodatime

I want to parse a string into DateTime object:

```
DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("M/d/yyyy HH:mm");
DateTime dt = fmt.parseDateTime(stringDate + " " +     stringTime).withZone(DateTimeZone.forID("Europe/Dublin"));
```

If I introduce time 06/22/2014 10:43 I get

> 06/22/2014 8:43 +0100,

but I want to get

> 06/22/2014 10:43 +0100

How can I do this?

Comment: Sorry, after some spent time i found the answer:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19002978/in-joda-time-how-to-convert-time-zone-without-changing-time
Thanks for 
@jgm

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should apply the timezone to the formatter, not to the `DateTime`. Otherwise, the date will have been parsed already in your local timezone, and you're merely transposing it to your desired timezone.

```
DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("M/d/yyyy HH:mm")
                        .withZone(DateTimeZone.forID("Europe/Dublin"));
DateTime dt = fmt.parseDateTime("06/22/2014 10:43");
```

Answer (score 1):

Look at this extended code:

```
String s = "06/22/2014 10:43";
DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("M/d/yyyy HH:mm"); // uses local zone
DateTime dt1 = fmt.parseDateTime(s).withZone(DateTimeZone.forID("Europe/Dublin"));
DateTime dt2 = fmt.withZone(DateTimeZone.forID("Europe/Dublin")).parseDateTime(s);
DateTime dt3 =
  fmt.parseDateTime(s).withZoneRetainFields(DateTimeZone.forID("Europe/Dublin"));
System.out.println(dt1); // 2014-06-22T09:43:00.000+01:00 (from my zone Berlin to Dublin)
System.out.println(dt2); // 2014-06-22T10:43:00.000+01:00
System.out.println(dt3); // 2014-06-22T10:43:00.000+01:00
```