# Handling multiple timezone in Java

Tags: java, mysql, date, timezone

I need to store multiple user details from different country. How can I store the dates in DB (in UTC format) and how can I show the dates to the users accorning to their time zones.
I am using Java and mySQL.

Comment: is there any  solution using Java 8?

Comment: Please take a look on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12487125/java-how-do-you-convert-a-utc-timestamp-to-local-time

Comment: To convert time between timezones [JodaTime](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19002978/in-joda-time-how-to-convert-time-zone-without-changing-time) is your best bet.

Comment: @Thiefster If the op is using Java 8 there is probably no need for JodaTime.

Comment: @SivaPasupathi Please search Stack Overflow before posting. This has been handled in hundreds if not thousands of existing Questions and Answers.

Comment: Suggest we reopen this question. I believe the persons voting to close it assumed that it was all about Java calendar and time data types, whereas the OP seemed satisfied with an answer as simple as the question that addressed the DBMS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In MySQL, use the `TIMESTAMP` data type in your tables.

For each user, store a `timezone` column, `VARCHAR(64)` is a good data type for that column. When a user registers to use your system, ask for the time zone value. Mine is `America/New_York`.  Yours might or might not be `Asia/Kolkata`.  For a user interface for this user-preference setting, the WordPress.org software has a good example.

Finally, whenever you establish a connection from your Java program to your DBMS in behalf of a user, issue the SQL command

```
 SET SESSION time_zone='(whatever tz string the user gave you)'
```

before you handle any user data.

This will cause all times going in to your tables to be converted to UTC, and all times coming out to be translated to local.  It works properly for `NOW()` and `CURDATE()`. Again, you must use `TIMESTAMP` and not `DATETIME` or `DATE` data types for this.

Make sure your server OS and default MySQL time zones are set to UTC. If you don't do this before you start loading information into your database, it will be almost impossible to fix. If you use a vendor to run MySQL, insist they get this right and fire the vendor if they don't have it right.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I will try implementing these steps.